# Getting references of a factory service (OSGI - AEM Context)

Tags: osgi, aem

I am trying to get references to a factory service I created (in AEM 6.4.6) and am failing. Here is the code (Did try searching for similar ones, but did not find a direct answer. I might not have searched enough or what i am doing might be completely wrong.. Looking forward to responses from experts).

Update 3: (Update 1 and 2 at the end) - This is a question on how i can get it using references. However would also be great if experts can share other methods.

**Service code (in the first bundle)**

```
public interface GodaDataServiceFactory {

    List<GodaDataBean> getData();

}
```

**Service Impl Code (Another bundle - Second bundle, Note its a factory)**

```
@Component(

        service = GodaDataServiceFactory.class,

        factory = "GodaDataServiceFactory",

        configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE

)

@Designate(ocd = GodaDataServiceFactoryConfig.class, factory = true)

public class GodaDataServiceFactoryJcrImpl implements GodaDataServiceFactory {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GodaDataServiceFactoryJcrImpl.class);

    @Override

    public List<GodaDataBean> getData() {

        return null;

    }

}
```

**Snaps of the configs**
[image]

[image]

**Reference**

**Option 1 (Direct reference):**

```
@Reference(target = "(sample=test)")

private GodaDataServiceFactory godaDataServiceFactory;
```

**Option 2 (Indirect using bind and unbind)**

```
    @Reference(

    name = "godaDataServiceFactory",

    cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MULTIPLE,

    policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,

    bind = "bindGodaDataServiceFactory",

    unbind = "unbindGodaDataServiceFactory")

    List<GodaDataServiceFactory> godaDataServiceFactoryList = new ArrayList<>();

    protected synchronized void bindGodaDataServiceFactory(final GodaDataServiceFactory config) {

    LOGGER.info("Goda config factory: {}", config);

    godaDataServiceFactoryList.add(config);

    }

protected synchronized void unbindGodaDataServiceFactory(final GodaDataServiceFactory config) {

godaDataServiceFactoryList.remove(config);

}
```

None of this seems to work. In the first case godaDataServiceFactory, it is null. The second case, the list is always empty. Note that the consumer is a servlet.

**My GitHub Repos**

Consumer -> https://github.com/GodaProjects/aem646

API -> https://github.com/GodaProjects/api

API IMPL -> https://github.com/GodaProjects/apiImplJcr

**Update 1:**

For option 1, The servlet remains unsatisfied.

Reference godaDataServiceFactory
Unsatisfied
Service Name: com.goda.core.services.GodaDataServiceFactory
Target Filter: (sample=test)
Cardinality: 1..1
Policy: static
Policy Option: reluctant
No Services bound

[image]

For the second option,the list remains empty

**Update 2**

Consumer project is created using Archetype 13 (has the servlet which consumes the factory service) -> https://github.com/GodaProjects/aem646

API project is created using Archetype 18 (has the API interface for the factory) -> https://github.com/GodaProjects/api

API IMPL project is created using Archetype 18 (has the implementation for the API which is in the API project) -> https://github.com/GodaProjects/apiImplJcr

Comment: have you tried just @Reference annotation without any options?

Comment: Yes, the same. In fact I figured out something. Requires a longer time to frame the response. Will do it after sometime.

Answer (score 2):

I think i got it. The root cause of the issue seemed to be having the same package structure in 3 separate bundles (aem652, api and apiJcrImpl have the same package com.goda.core). This qualifies in to the realm of split bundles which is discouraged by OSGi anyway. Also the behavior was a lot unpredictable. It was looking for classes from one bundle in another where it does does not exist and was throwing "classnotfound"s. Got really confusing. Anyway its clearing that they were masking each other in a pattern, which I neither had time nor energy to figure out. Suffice to say, what i did was not very prudent. So here goes. this is the solution.

**Edit:**

```
Consumer https://github.com/GodaProjects/aem652
API https://github.com/GodaProjects/api
API Impl https://github.com/GodaProjects/apiImplJcr
```